# Keep image ratio when parent div is a percent

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to have images span the width of the screen and keep their image ratio at the same time. Basically, there are 4 images that need to be equally spread across the width of the screen and need to keep image ratio at the same time with no space or padding between the images.

I made a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/travi5567/pen/YXoZxb?editors=110) of what I have tried to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="featured-products">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <p>
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
       </p>
   </li>
   <li>
       <p>
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
       </p>
   </li>
   <li>
       <p>
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
       </p>
   </li>
   <li>
       <p>
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
        <img src=" http://placehold.it/320x410" alt="" />
       </p>
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

LESS/CSS:

```
.featured-products {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            p {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                img:nth-child(1){
                    background-size: cover;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    max-height: 100%;
                }
                img:nth-child(2){
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got control over the HTML? What's the purpose of the second (hidden) image?

Comment: Don't get what is wrong to be honest. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Should do the trick. Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPzpeN?editors=110